# PHP accessing an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm a bit confused.

I have an array:

```
<?php 

$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'pf');
        print_r($terms);
?>
```

And it outputs:

> Array ( [15] => stdClass Object (
>   [term_id] => 15 [name] => Text [slug]
>   => text [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 33 [taxonomy] =>
>   pf [description] => An PF article.
>   [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 [object_id]
>   => 694 ) )

And I want just to output slug ("text" in this case) instead of the whole array.

So I'm doing:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'pf');
             echo $terms["slug"]; ?>
```

And it outputs nothing.

This gives no results as well:

```
echo "{$terms['slug']}";
```

Any ideas?

UPDATED!!!

I can't use $term[15]->slug since my script will be based on [taxonomy] (pf in this case)! :) So it's impossible to do that without foreach loop?

Answer (score 5):

terms array 15 index contain object access like this

```
echo $term[15]->slug
```

Comment: Is there a way of accessing $terms by "taxonomy" (pf in this case)? Because the ID may vary.

Comment: @meritum: ID will be vary you have to use `foreach` loop here. `foreach($term as $object) { echo $object->slug; }`

Answer (score 3):

there is stdclass object at index 15 of the inside arry which can be converted/accessed as array by casting but try this insted

```
$term[15]->slug
```

Answer (score -1):

Following up on Pekka's answer, if you reformat your print_r() output, you'd get:

```
Array (
    [15] => stdClass Object (
        [term_id] => 15
        [name] => Text
        [slug] => text
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 33
        [taxonomy] => pf
        [description] => An PF article.
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 3
        [object_id] => 694
    )
)
```

When dumping out a variable with print_r(), it's good practice to surround the call with `<pre>` tags - print_r doesn't do any HTML-ification of the data, so the nice indentation it does with arrays gets lost when viewed in an HTML page. Using the `<pre>` tags preserves the formatting. using `var_dump()` will do the same, but also add type/size data to the dump output.

Comment: I did not down voted but this does not answer OP's question anyway

Comment: At the time I wrote this, pekka's answer was still listed. However, he's now deleted it.